# How to search through all Nodes (including children nodes)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

I have a WinForm tree view (property is named "*tvwAcct*") where I would like to be able to search through all the existing nodes with a given string ("*txtName.Text*"), and if it already exists, to give the user a Message box warning to stop duplicate entries. It needs to be able to search all parent nodes and also child nodes. My current tree structure is as follows:

> Bank account name
>
> -> Sub-account name 1
>
> -> Sub-account name 2
>
> ->  Sub-account name 3

I have looked at [MSDN.Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) and can see that the **Nodes.Find** method exists.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub txtName_Validating(eventSender As Object, eventArgs As CancelEventArgs) Handles txtName.Validating
    Dim Cancel As Boolean = eventArgs.Cancel
    Dim b As Boolean = True

    ' [ other 'if' conditions here ]

    ElseIf (tvwAcct.Nodes.Find(txtName.Text, b) Then
        MyMsgBox("Sorry, this account name already exists. Please try again with a different name.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Cancel = True
```

With this code, I get an error message which says:

> Value of type TreeNode() cannot be converted to 'Boolean'.

I would be open to another way of doing this if this isn't going to work, such as getting the node text values, and then putting these into an Array list and querying the array list instead. But I'm not experienced enough to know how to do this.

Does anyone know where I've gone wrong please? Or can provide a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [TreeView.Nodes.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) function returns an array of nodes, not a true / false value.

Try it like this:

```
ElseIf tvwAcct.Nodes.Find(txtName.Text, b).Length > 0 Then
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I am now not given any error messages which is great. However, during testing, when I click the 'Done' button, duplicate nodes are still being added and saved to the TreeView despite this fix. Is my logic correct?

Comment: @Pepsi_Max You didn't show enough of your code.  You need to prevent the node from being added to the TreeView.

Answer (score 1):

The Find method, search by node keys not text. So, if you need to search your nodes by text, you will need to implement your own method. I prefer to use LINQ for such tasks, however it may be not the optimum solution:

```
Dim treeNodes = tvwAcct.Nodes.Cast(Of TreeNode).Where(Function(x) x.Text = txtName.Text).ToArray


If treeNodes.Length > 0 Then
     MessageBox.Show("Sorry, this account name already exists. Please try again with a different name.")
     Cancel = True
End If
```